# What's this black box?

Tags: surviv.io

It's been a few times already that I stumbled upon this black box with an eye on it:

[image: Spoopy black box.]

I have no idea what it is. It appears as a small black square on the map, it is probably indestructible, and also pretty spooky. I've tried to destroy it in many ways:

- Punching it
- Stabbing it
- Shooting it with all kinds of guns, SMGs and shotguns
- Throwing grenades at it
- Pressing  <kbd>F</kbd>
- Staring it right in the eye

None of my methods worked. What is this thing?! Can it be destroyed? Can it drop loot? Is it just a troll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an eye crate/[Hardstone](https://survivio.fandom.com/wiki/Hardstone_Block) block.
It is impervious to everything (don't waste ammo) save for:

1.Airstrikes (from strobes) Make sure to not miss with the strobe, stand far away and throw.

2.Airdrops (use the Flare Gun next to the Block)

3.The Sledgehammer from the bunker in the [Alternate Barn](https://survivio.fandom.com/wiki/Barn#Alternate_Barn). Smack it a few times and it will open. (You can also use the Stone Hammer, but that's event-only)

It drops:
Upon breakage, you can find one round of .45 ACP , Peacemaker , AWM-S , USAS-12 , M9 , 9mm , M4A1-S, BAR M1918, M249, PKP Pecheneg or Flare Gun(each weapon also has ammo along with it). You can find one inside the Eye Bunker in Woods Mode, behind the stone wall, and multiple others randomly scattered around the map in every map. (suriv.io wiki). If it drops a gun, it drops ammo as well.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

war hammer, stone hammer,[image: is in dark green house for stone hammer in bunker off darkest green house(only 1 house have stone hammer-))))))]

but i am vietnam people

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: and slegde hammer(in bunker of dark green house) (fixed)